# Instagram location endpoind media/recent always return empty array

Tags: json, api, location, instagram-api

I always get empty JSON response by https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/LOCATION-ID/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

e.g. api.instagram.com/v1/locations/215700153/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

JSON Response:

```
    {"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

Althouh I tried some other location ids, all of the results are empty too.

Any suggestions?

..
For example about my ACCESS-TOKEN
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN correctly return array with locations
Parameter scope=public_content

Comment: Was this resolved?I am having the same issue using `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` which returns virtually the same `Object {pagination: Object, meta: Object, data: Array[0]}`. When expanded the Object shows a data array with a length of 0.

Answer (score 3):

It works for now. However, the response depends on your token. Some tokens seems like valid but return you empty responses.

After I faced this problem I started using http://services.chrisriversdesign.com/instagram-token/ service to generate instagram tokens which work correctly with instagram media API requests.

Comment: This is an absolute life saver! Well maybe not life saving, but really removes the pain in the a** retrieving an access token.

Comment: This worked for me. It looks like the difference was my token only requested public_content but his requested profile data as well.

Comment: The difference is probably because your app is in Sandbox mode and therefore with restricted access to content. That other app is probably in live mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same thing right now.

**Here's what most likely caused the OP issue:**

Judging by the date and time of your post, it was an issue with the Facebook and Instagram servers being down for about 90 mins.

According to a Jan 26 post on 
[Facebook's developer page:](https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/393998364112264/)
*"Facebook and Instagram experienced a major outage tonight from 22:10 until 23:10 PST. Our engineers identified the cause of the outage and recovered the site quickly. You should now see decreasing error rates while our systems stabilize. We don't expect any other break in service. I'll post another update within 30 mins. Thank you for your patience."*